# Error in MySQL code- Syntax error at Inner join

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Tables - Department and Employees. I am trying to display department  that hire at least 1 employee which must be sorted by department id

Department Table

```
create table department (
      dept_id integer not null,
      dept_name varchar(30) not null,
      dept_location varchar(30) not null,
      unique(dept_id)
  );
```

Employee Table

```
  create table employee (
      emp_id integer not null,
      emp_name varchar(50) not null,
      dept_id integer not null,
      salary integer not null,
      unique(emp_id)
  );
```

I have written this SQL query

```
SELECT  department.dept_id, sum(salary),count(*) 
FROM employee 
     INNER JOIN department
       ON employee.dept_id =department.dept_id
        GROUP BY department.dept_id
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;
ORDER BY department.dept_id
```

I am getting

```
syntax error at or near "ORDER"
```

Comment: Delete `;` before order by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the order by clause in wrong position  ..

the order must be the  last clause

```
SELECT  department.dept_id, sum(employee.salary), count(*) 
FROM employee 
     INNER JOIN department
       ON employee.dept_id =department.dept_id
        GROUP BY department.dept_id
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
ORDER BY department.dept_id;
```

this because the ORDER BY just work for result  presentation

Comment: .. try execute the code  .. the error message in  based on wrong sequence of the clause  .. and during the parsing the inner join  is in an wron postion  respected thye previsous code .. but the reason is the wrong position of the ORDER BY clause  ..

Comment: Use the table's name: `ORDER BY department.dept_id`

Comment: if you have ambiguity  .. then just add  the table name  to the order by  ... answer  updated ..

Comment: @forpas   thanks for the suggestion  ..  upvote somewhere

Comment: @Karan  .. update your question and show me you exect error message

Comment: Does this error has something to do with error in logic?

Comment: have you checked the position of the semicolon  .. look at my code  .. the semicolon is after  the order by clause  ..  in your code in before the order by clause .. try check  ..